# Whiling defining a build in VSTS, 'app center test' and 'app center distribute' tabs are disabled

Tags: azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

First I tried to locate the project's repository in App Center to build it for testing, which did not work out. Then I tried to build the app in VSTS. I saw that I can connect it to app center. But the tabs are shown disabled. Other than that, the app built successfully. Anyone know the fixes to that?

Update: ALTHOUGH, I have found a workaround so build the app in app center, but I am still curious. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZIOv.png)
why are these tabs disabled? Or what could cause them to be disabled?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of exactly what you mean? I'll take a look in my vsts instance and see if I see anything similar.

Comment: What's the type of the app do you manage in app center? And can you share the whole VSTS build logs here?  And did you update the app or SDK version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click that task > Enable selected task(s).

[image]

The edit build definition permission for your account is required.

[image]